# Looking for a map of the xinit/startx rabbithole

Tags: x11, zsh

Can someone point me to an authoritative guide to the X11 initialization sequence that *also* explains how it dovetails with the shell's initialization?

---

I'm trying to figure out how to make some environment variables available to programs that I normally start via a desktop launcher.

But when I try to determine the order of events after I log in, and in particular, what sources what, it's like going "down the rabbit hole": every alleged guide I find through Google tells me a different story.  (To make matters worse, one of the pages I found said that this order of events "depends on the distribution".  I fervently hope and pray that this is not true.)  At any rate, none of them is particularly clear on the relationship between the sourcing of shell initialization files (in my case, .zshenv and friends) and the rest of the X11-related initialization.

Comment: I have zero experience here, but if you're just looking for what spawns what, you may be able to generate a mapping function via the output of strace -f startx

Comment: There is a close reason "Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications).". You may want to [edit] to put yourself firmly into one camp or another here.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: I'll delete my question as soon as I can.

Comment: I didn't say you should delete it, just [edit] so that it clearly fits in (either seeking official documentation, or asking something concrete here). At the moment it's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: the question I intended to ask is off-topic, so it should be deleted.  I have no problem with that.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: I rolled back your edits, sorry.  After all, you deleted what I consider the main part of the question, and left only what I added only as explanatory stuff.  If the question is going to be under my name, I'd like it to be substantially as I wrote it.  I'd gladly delete it if I could.  (Unfortunately, I can't, thanks to Michael P.)  Alternatively, if there's a way to take my name out of the question (i.e. change it to "community wiki" or some such), then please do so, and then the question may be modified in any way you like.

Comment: this is an excellent question. it is my hope that no one will vote to close it on those grounds - though it is possible someone might - mh thought so anyway. ill vote to keep it open - id like to know the answer. i think perhaps mh was commenting for the same reason i am - this question has a lot of potential and shouldnt be deleted. to guard against it maybe you could find another way to phrase it that would prevent its doing so? for me, at least? i want the answer!

Comment: Yeah, what he said.

Comment: Also, the only part that I deleted was "Can someone point me to an authoritative guide"; the rest of **what you wrote** in the first paragraph **was in the title in the form of a question**. If that isn't "substantially as you wrote it"....

Answer (score 1):

The arch wiki pages are a decent starting point for most of the confusing stuff here. You could start at:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc for example.